# Problems running Python script via Cygwin

Tags: python, windows, cygwin

I'm trying to run my Python scripts via Cygwin from Windows. I'm getting the following error when running Python. The problem is when running Python via Cygwin it then runs the command via the Windows instance of Python i.e. `C:\Python32\python.exe` which then can't find the `py` file I'm linking to using the Cygwin way.

```
$ /cygdrive/c/Python32/python /cygdrive/c/elf/GIT/src/sfgenctl.py
C:\Python32\python.exe: can't open file '/cygdrive/c/elf/GIT/src/sfgenctl.py':
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Is there a way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way of doing this was to install the Python Cygwin add on. Thanks for the helo guys.

Answer (score 3):

Use `cygpath` to convert it to Windows paths before passing it to `python.exe`:

```sh
/cygdrive/c/Python32/python "`cygpath -w /cygdrive/c/elf/GIT/src/sfgenctl.py`"
```

Comment: or you could just use windows path to start with ... cygwin understands it ... just doesnt like it much

Comment: @Joran: I was assuming that the path was being dynamically generated by some other program. If it really is just a constant, then sure, change it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by:

1. Go into the folder where the script is. `cd /cygdrive/c/elf/GIT/src/`
2. run `python -i sfgenctl.py`

Notice the `-i` flag.